# MySQL/PHP error, SQL syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use php to open a csv file and update the selected data, which it reads correctly and some of the column data may be blank on some rows, but i keep getting the following error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to            your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' address2 = 1654 E 13TH ST APT 1E, address3 = ' at line 4
```

when trying to run the following command

```
$sql = "update vicidial_list
              SET
                  address1 = $fileop[7], 
                  address2 = $fileop[8],
                  address3 = $fileop[9]
            where
                  phone_number = $fileop[0]
              and
                  list_id = '82429711'
              ;";

if(!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: ' .mysql_error());
```

Comment: 1- your query is vulnerable to SQL injection, 2- you should enclose all string values with single quotes!

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around your values, or else it won't be able to know when it ends or starts.

Like this: (or you can use prepare statements, and that would also solve your problem)

```
$sql = "update vicidial_list
              SET
                  address1 = '$fileop[7]', 
                  address2 = '$fileop[8]', 
                  address3 = '$fileop[9]'
            where
                  phone_number = $fileop[0]
              and
                  list_id = '82429711'
                ;";
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't use single quote symbol, so you get this error.

You have to use `'` symbol in your queries:

```
$sql = "update vicidial_list

        SET
          address1 = '$fileop[7]', 
          address2 = '$fileop[8]', 
          address3 = '$fileop[9]'

        where
           phone_number = '$fileop[0]'

        and
           list_id = '82429711'
        ;";
```

Also, better to use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), not simple `mysql_query()` function.